Expected Number of Books to Examine Before Drawing All 6
Tom is searching for the 6 books he needs in a random pile of 30 books. What is the expected number of books must he examine before finding all 6 books he needs (PUMAC Combo Round 2007)?
I'm just wondering if I have the correct approach to this problem. This feels really similar to that one question asking the expected number of cards you draw before you see an Ace so I took a similar approach. Let $X_0, \ldots, X_6$ be the number of books drawn in between the 6 books of interest. Basically what I'm saying is that we draw $X_0$ books and then draw the first book of interest. Then we draw $X_1$ books and then the second book of interest, and so on and so forth.
The answer to the question should be $6 + \mathbb{E}[X_0+X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5]$. All of these are the same by symmetry and $\mathbb{E}[X_0] = (30-6)/7 = 24/7$. Thus, the answer is $6\cdot 24/7 + 6 = \boxed{186/7}$.

Alternative approach:
Consider the following tableau:
- B-1 - B-2 - B-3 - B-4 - B-5 - B-6 -

The $~6~$ books are distributed among the $~30~$ book positions so that $~7~$ islands are created between the books.  Reading these islands from left to right, let $~x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_7~$ denote the respective sizes of these islands.
Then, you have that $~x_1 + \cdots + x_7 = 24,~$ so the expected size of $~x_7~$ is $~24/7.~$
Therefore, the expected number of books is
$$30 - x_7 = 30 - 24/7 = 186/7.$$

Interesting, you essentially ask what is the expected number of irrelevant books you will see from the back, until you see the last of the 6 books. This is of course equivalent to the expected number of books to see the first of the 6 books from the front. Cool!

Great job noticing the similarity between this problem and the expected number of draws needed to find a specific card! You're on the right track, and here’s a detailed breakdown to confirm your approach.
Step 1: Understanding the Problem
Tom is searching for 6 specific books in a random pile of 30 books. The question is asking for the expected number of books he needs to examine before finding all 6 books of interest.
This problem is actually a variation of the “coupon collector’s problem,” where we calculate the expected number of trials needed to collect a complete set of distinct items.
Step 2: Setting Up the Expectation
To solve this, let’s define XiXi​ as the number of books Tom examines between finding each successive book of interest. For instance, X0X0​ represents the books examined before finding the first book of interest, X1X1​ is between the first and second, and so on.
The total expected number of books to examine would be:
Expected Total=6+E[X0+X1+X2+X3+X4+X5]
Expected Total=6+E[X0​+X1​+X2​+X3​+X4​+X5​]
Step 3: Calculating Each E[Xi]E[Xi​]
Each XiXi​ represents the number of books examined between each pair of books of interest. Since there are 30 books total and 6 are of interest, the probability of drawing a book of interest is roughly 630306​. By linearity of expectation, we calculate each E[Xi]E[Xi​] as the ratio of books not of interest to the number of gaps between books of interest:
E[Xi]=30−66+1=247
E[Xi​]=6+130−6​=724​
Step 4: Summing Up the Expected Value
So, the total expected number of books examined is:
6+6⋅247=6+1447=1867
6+6⋅724​=6+7144​=7186​
Final Answer
Therefore, the expected number of books Tom needs to examine before finding all 6 books of interest is:
1867
7186​

Unsure if you have typos in your answer.  The expected number of books must be some number less than $~30.$
